# JS: find lowest/highest number from array within a specific range

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, apply, min

I have an array with a few nums:

`var arr = ["10","14","23","2","21","17","72","16","73","52"];`

I know I can use `Math.min.apply(Math, arr)` to get from an array the lowest number or use `Math.max.apply(Math,arr)` for the maximum number, but now I want only the minimum or maximum number from the last 3 elements in the array.

Any suggestions how I could do this?

Comment: "last 3 characters" or last 3 elements?

Comment: can you use this `arr.slice(Math.max(arr.length - 3, 1))` and then apply the `Math` functions to the output array?

Comment: @Vohuman, the last 3 elements. Changed it in the description.

Comment: Yes, you can use `Array.prototype.slice` for slicing the array, then you can use the sliced array. `var slicedArr = arr.slice(-3)`

Comment: @Vohuman : you clearly haven't read it. I want from the last 3 elements, the highest or lowest number. I don't wanna slice anything ;/

Comment: It seems you clearly haven't understood what was the point. `Math.max.apply(Math, slicedArr)`. `slice` doesn't modify the original array.

Comment: Just a side note: No one noticed that, but the array is broken: missing `"` after `"73`.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), you can extract a range of values within an array. This will allow you to only perform the `min()` and `max()` function on the values within the designated range.

The `minmax()` function below will return an object with `min` and `max` values.

```js
function minmax(arr, begin, end) {
    arr = [].slice.apply(arr, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));
    return {
        'min' : Math.min.apply(Math, arr),
        'max' : Math.max.apply(Math, arr)
    }
}

var values = ["10","14","23","2","21","17","72","16","73","52"];
var result = minmax(values, -3);

document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result, undefined, '    ');
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

Comment: That's an advanced solution. Nice approach!